# How can I make a web service-container communicate with a worker-container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I have two images. One with a webservice written in Go and another one with a Ruby worker. The webservice calls the worker like this:

```
func (img image) applyBlur() error {
    blurCommand := exec.Command("ruby", "controller/blurImage.rb", img.path)
    return blurCommand.Run()
}
```

How can I make the two containers connect with each other?

I made the two following Dockerfiles for the images (Please, have in mind I"ve just started learning docker).

Worker:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.1-base-ubuntu18.04

LABEL version="0.0.1"

LABEL maintainer="mjg"

RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y python3.6 python3-pip \
    && apt install -y ruby

WORKDIR /cvlib

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip; \
    pip3 install opencv-python tensorflow cvlib; \
    apt install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev libgl1-mesa-glx; \
    apt remove -y python3-pip

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

VOLUME [ "/app/blurred-images", "app/source-images" ]
```

Webservice:

```
FROM golang:1.15.2

LABEL version="0.0.1"

LABEL maintainer="mjg"

WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/m-goncalves/webservice

COPY server/  server/

COPY cmd/ cmd/

COPY index.html .

RUN GOBIN=/go/bin go install cmd/webservice/webservice.go

ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/webservice

EXPOSE 8080

VOLUME [ "/source-images", "/blurred-images"
```

Comment: Please add the docker-compose yaml file as well in the question. Both containers need to be in the same network. You can exec into the container and check the connectivity with the other container.

Comment: Thanks for the help, You'll. I still don't have a docker-compose file. Is it necessary to get this working? I am really a beginner. Considering you comment I am assuming I will need to create a compose-file and a network for the containers. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. or else if you start the containers separately you need to first create a network and then set the network to both those containers

Comment: Thanks a lot man. This will help me a lot. Now I know at least how to start trying.

Comment: You seem to have attached a couple of images to your question where you say you have the Dockerfiles.  Can you replace these with the actual text of the files?  `docker build` doesn't understand the PNG files.

Comment: Replaced, David!

Answer (score 1):

In order to have connectivity between the containers that you have you must make sure that they are inside the same network. This could be achieved by setting both containers inside one docker-compose file. You can explicitly set the network as well if you want.

Second option would be to create a docker network first and then start both containers individually but setting the common network created earlier.

Refer the [docker compose networking documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! This will help me a lot. I will check the documentation to see how I can do that.